# How to check if file with same name has been attached in PowerApps?

Tags: attachment, powerapps

I want user to add files with different names. Currently default PowerApps control allows attachment of files with same names. But, while saving the form it saves only 1 file. I want to restrict users from attaching files with same name.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new collection to store the name of the files user is uploading through attachment control using "onAttach" method.
When user tries to attach the file with same name check the collection if the file name exist's. Display a error/warning message Or Disable the save/submit button for that form.